# Installed App from TestFlight crashes due to alleged UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, testflight, uisearchcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I implemented Dark Mode with the current beta version of Xcode in a relatively old app. I uploaded these to TestFlight for my testers. However, this crashes immediately for anyone who has the public beta of iOS 13.

I've integrated Crashlytics into the app, and the cause of these crashes is as follows:

> `UISearchDisplayController` is no longer supported when using this version of iOS. Please migrate your application to `UISearchController`.

All `UISearchDisplayController` instances have already been replaced by the `UISearchController`. The app doesn't use the `UISearchDisplayController` anymore. There is no longer any links to the `UISearchDisplayController`. Nevertheless, these crashes continue to occur, but only from the installations of TestFlight.

If the app is installed directly with Xcode as a "Debug" or "Release" on an iPhone with the public beta, the crash does not occur.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to check this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchdisplaycontroller

Comment: search the libraries you are using

Comment: @sulthan I did a search across all libraries and none of them use the UISearchDisplayController or its delegate.

Comment: Cant really do anything else, just makes sure you don't have any lingering `UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate` or it's instance remaining

Comment: @Tj3n Did you search specifically for `UISearchDisplayController`, or only the delegate? Also try to run grep over your project folder. There could be a reference in xibs.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

After receiving the same error and finding no references to `UISearchDisplayController` across our app, we realized we needed to search for and replace `searchDisplayController` from within one of our storyboards. That corrected the issue after resubmitting a beta to TestFlight.

Comment: Thanks a lot, searching for `searchDisplayController` directly in the sourcecode of the storyboard was the solution.

Comment: With what did you replace <searchDisplayController> ? Replacing it with <searchController> gives an error.

Comment: @dnzzcn UISearchDisplayController is deprecated. So you have to replace everything related to it in code and storyboard. You could use UISearchController instead.

Comment: @dnzzcn Did you find out what to replace `searchDisplayController ` with?

Comment: I couldn’t find an alternative and just commented them out. I didn’t encounter an error yet, so it should be ok I guess.

Comment: For me, removing all instances of searchDisplayController tag and removing them worked.

Comment: A good migration guide to switch from UISearchDisplayController to UISearchController is written by Keith Harrison: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller/

Comment: We just got rejected during App Store review by this issue. The problem was that in two places the `searchDisplayController` outlet was still connected in IB, even though the relevant view controllers had long since been modified. We didn't catch this in testing because apparently it doesn't crash when run in the simulator.

Comment: Btw, an easy way to search for it is opening Terminal in your project home folder and run:

`grep -r searchDisplayController *`

Answer (score 40):

It was working on simulator but all beta tester claimed it crashed. The problem was in story board. Search for these in your views. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can delete these from IB and any IBOutlet to these. I will be easier to add search in code rather than IB

Answer (score 2):

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UISearchDisplayController is no longer supported when linking against this version of iOS. Please migrate your application to UISearchController.'

Successfully Runs locally, but crashed on testFlight app.

**Fix:**

I found UISearchDisplayController which stuck in one of the storyboard and wasn't used anymore. Search for the **searchDisplayController** directly into sourcecode of the storyboard and just removed it.