# UISearchDisplayController is no longer supported when linking against this version of iOS

Tags: ios13, google-maps-sdk-ios

Unable to use Googleplaces SDk, No where I'm using "UISearchDisplayController" in my project. So searched in my project which is showing in GooglePlaces

[image]

I'm no where using "GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource", I'm Using "GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController" for getting the places.

Comment: Can you please post your code? UISearchDisplayController has been deprecated since iOS 8.

Answer (score 18):

When adding a searchBar to UIViewController in Storyboard, the UISearchBarDisplayController will be added. Just click to it add press 'Delete'
[image]

Answer (score 10):

I have just removed searchDisplayController used in storyboard viewController.

Search for searchDisplayController and just remove it and it's outlet if created.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a search Display Controller in my storyboard, which is not pulling up when i search like this. so search with "searchDisplayController" in each storyBoards. Referred from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819165/installed-app-from-testflight-crashes-due-to-alleged-uisearchdisplaycontroller)

Answer (score 0):

in xcode<General minimum deployments change version to 12.4 fix this error