# iOS app runs fine if installed through Xcode, but crashes on one particular view controller when installed through TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

I have an iOS (Swift 4.2) app that runs fine on the simulator, and runs fine on an iPhone when installed from Xcode (ver 11.4). Even if the iPhone is then disconnected from the computer, the app still runs fine. However, when I archive to TestFlight and install it from there, 99% of the app works fine, but when I try to go to one particular view controller, it crashes the app. I have downloaded the crash logs from TestFlight, but I'm afraid I don't know how to interpret them. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, deleting derived data, etc. but nothing has solved it. It always crashes when installed through TestFlight. Is there anything else I can check?

[Symbolicated Crash File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5s3qx7dwz21rvev/symbolicated.crash?dl=0)

Comment: Search for instructions on how to symbolicate a crash log then add a symbolicated log to your question.

Comment: Did you try to run a release configuration from the Xcode locally?

Comment: Link to symbolicated crash log added to question.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the issue was, but I resolved it by re-creating the ViewController from scratch. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

When you archive the configuration is different than when running from Xcode.

In case you have more than one Target check if the view controller that is crashing is checked for the target that is selected to archive.

1. Click on your ViewController file and also on the storyboard where it's included.
2. Open the File Inspector and check that all targets under Target Membership are selected
3. Select them and run again

Another solution may be to run locally the release configuration and debug the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is due to `UISearchDisplayControllerNoLongerSupported`. This answer [Installed App from TestFlight crashes due to alleged UISearchDisplayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819165/installed-app-from-testflight-crashes-due-to-alleged-uisearchdisplaycontroller) might solve your problem.